# Can't reach the recreated activity on Firebase task execution after orientation change

Tags: android, firebase, activity-lifecycle

I am using some Firebase tasks in my app and while it is executing a task, I want do display a loading dialog which can't be cancelled by tapping outside or pressing back etc. and will be dismissed at the end of the task. For example;

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
LoadingDialog ld = new LoadingDialog();
ld.show(fm, "dialog");

storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(uri -> {
    Fragment dialog = fm.findFragmentByTag("dialog");
    if (dialog != null) {
        LoadingDialog ld = (LoadingDialog) dialog;
        ld.dismiss();
    }
});
```

It is working as expected when orientation state is fixed but when orientation change during the process `fm.findFragmentByTag("dialog");` returns null after task is complete.

My LoadingDialog class which extends DialogFragment;

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    assert activity != null;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder =
            new AlertDialog.Builder(activity, R.style.LoadingDialog);

    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_loading, null);
    builder.setView(view);
    setCancelable(false);

    return builder.create();
}


@Override
public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(this, tag);
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

Why can't I find my dialog fragment using its tag?

**Edit:** I found the reason of this, I can't reach my dialog fragment because of activity recreation. The old activity which I executed the task is destroyed and it tries to access fragment manager from the destroyed activity.

Thanks to @Bö macht Blau, I implemented my `ViewModel` class and passed some information by using `MutableLiveData` objects to my activity where I observe execution of Firebase tasks. Some example code for java;

```
public class AuthViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    public MutableLiveData<LoginInfo> loginInfoLiveData;

    public AuthViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        loginInfoLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    }

    public void signIn(String email, String password) {
        FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
                    firebaseUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
                    LoginInfo loginInfo = new LoginInfo(
                            task.isSuccessful(),
                            firebaseUser != null && firebaseUser.isEmailVerified(),
                            task.getException());
                    loginInfoLiveData.postValue(loginInfo);
                });
    }
}
```

at `onCreate` method of the activity;

```
authViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this,
        ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(getApplication()))
        .get(AuthViewModel.class);

authViewModel.loginInfoLiveData.observe(this, loginInfo -> {
    hideLoadingDialog();
    if (loginInfo.isSuccessful()) {
        if (loginInfo.isEmailVerified()) {
            startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        } else {
            auth.signOut();
            toast(R.string.verification_error);
        }
    } else {
        handleException(loginInfo.getException());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the code related to Firebase tasks to a `ViewModel` (or even to a repository which exposes `LiveData` objects to the `ViewModel`). As soon as the task has finished successfully, the `ViewModel` can update a `MutableLiveData<Boolean> _loadingSuccess` by calling

```
 _loadingSuccess.postValue(true)
```

The `ViewModel` in turn can expose a `LiveData<Boolean> loadingSuccess = _loadingSuccess` which your `Fragment` or  `Activity` can observe.

Since a `ViewModel` will survive a configuration change, the `Fragment` or `Activity` can re-register the observer each time it comes to the foreground

Code example for a `Fragment`

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    viewModel.loadingSuccess.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { success ->
        run {
            if(success != null){
                dismissLoadingDialog()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For more information on LiveData and Viewmodels, see the [Guide to app architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide)

Comment: I have another problem about this, when I use `postValue` it triggers observe method which is normal. But when config changed (activity recreated) observe method is also called without calling `postValue`.

Comment: @RasitAyaz - yes, that's normal for LiveData. In your case, if the value is `true` you can check whether the loading dialog is still showing and if so dismiss it. In addition to that, you can post `false` once you start a new loading process. Not because you want to take any action, only be sure that there is no `true` from the execution of a previous Firebase task. LiveData and one shot messages can be a little bit tricky. There are several posts on this topic, see for example [LiveData with single events](https://proandroiddev.com/livedata-with-single-events-2395dea972a8)